# Docusign: RestAPI and Authoritative Copy

Tags: docusignapi

I know I can set the authoritative copy property on an envelope by setting the authoritativeCopy property of the envelope object.

Okay...now what? The documentation leaves a LOT to be desired. I don't see anything in the SDK except setting and getting the property. So Docusign has an authoritative copy of my document. What do I do now? Do I retrieve it if needed (if so, how?) Does it just sit there forever twiddling its authoritative thumbs, never to be heard from again? If one needs the a.c. (whatever that means) do they have to get it off the Docusign website?

I'm just a lowly developer: I worry about the *how*, not the *why*, and now the client's asking.

RestAPI, PHP SDK

Answer (score 0):

This is a unique (And only AFAIK) case where you can do something in the SOAP API but not in the REST API.

See documentation about [how to export the authoritative copy](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/how-to/authoritative-copy/).

The reason this is not in the REST API is that this is a very risky/dangerous operation. Once you do this, it cannot be undone, ever, at all. Even if you call customer support. This is one of these situations where you should be very very very careful because you are taking an irreversible action. So be 100% sure this is what you want/need.

Comment: Cool. Let's say I don't ever export it. What then? Is it just on Docusign forever, and we get to it there?

Comment: yup, but you can still download copies as needed